# "List comprehensions" directly in for loop line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Is it possible to add a "list comprehensions" directly in for loop line? Current code:

```py
cubes = [i**3 for i in range(5)]
    for value in cubes:
        print(value)
```

I want to write something like (this obviously doesn't work):

```py
for value in cubes = [i**3 for i in range(5)]:
    print(value)
```

or

```py
cubes = [ ]
    for value in cubes = [i**3 for i in range(5)]:
        print(value)
```

Comment: Just remove `cubes  = `

Comment: `for value in [i**3 for i in range(5)]:`? Just replace the identifier with the expression you'd assigned to it.

Comment: Ultimately, you need to print out values, I suggest no list-comprehension here.

Comment: Do you want both the printout and keep the list cubes for something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply just put the expression in the loop as is:

```
for value in [i**3 for i in range(5)]:
    print(value)
```

output:

```
0
1
8
27
64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want both the list `cubes` for later in the code and want to print, you can do everything in the list comprehension by exploiting the fact that `print` returns `None`:

```
cubes = [print(i**3) or i**3  for i in range(5)]
```

Is this recommended? NO! It's a clear breach of ["The Zen of Python" (PEP20)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 1):

If `n` for your `range` is sufficiently large, using a list comprehension for your loop will hang before it even begins. You might want to abstract away the loop filtering by using `yield`:

```
def create_numbers(n):
    for x in range(n):
        yield x**3

for i in create_numbers(5):
    print(i)
```

`yield` will give you those values one at a time, only calculating the next value when `next()` is invoked by the loop. This way your loop looks nicer and doesn't iterate over that list 2*n times

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you keep the code you have now:

```
cubes = [i**3 for i in range(5)]
for value in cubes:
    print(value)
```

It's clear what it does, and it is correct. There's little reason to eliminate a single line of code at the risk of changing that.

---

That said, Python 3.8 will introduce *assignment expressions*, which *can* (if I am reading [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) correctly; no similar examples appear there) be used to eliminate that line of code:

```
for value in cubes := [i**3 for i in range(5)]:
    print(value)
```

Time will tell if this will be considered good, or at least acceptable, style.